# tlmgr doesn't run texhash automatically after installing a package

Tags: packages, tlmgr

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and installed TeX live 2020 using the TUG net installer. As I don't have much free space, I decided to install only some basic packages and to install what I need manually (or using [`texliveonfly`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly?lang=en)). Happily, I can install any package using the usual `tlmgr install <package>`.

What is bothering me now is that the package remains hidden in the system until I, manually, run `sudo texhash`. `tlmgr` seems to do `mktexlsr` automatically, but it isn't sufficient to update my TeX packages tree.

*A priori*, wouldn't be that hard just do `tlmgr install <package> && sudo texhash`. However, I can't tell `texliveonfly` to do that when I'm compiling third-party packages (when I just don't know what to install). Because of this, I need to rerun `texliveonfly document.tex && sudo texhash` for each package that it needs to install.

I would like to be able to only use `mktexlsr` (that `tlmgr` do by itself) or to get `tlmgr` running `texhash` also.

Comment: doesn't the non sudo version install in TEXMFHOME (which is not usually guarded by `!!` so files should be found by file search not needing texhash/mktexlsr)

Comment: I tried to `chown` the `ls-R` files so that I can run `texhash` without sudo. It's working now (including `mktexlsr`), but it's still strange...

Comment: that's what I mean: TEXMFHOME   (`~/texmf` in linux) doesn't use ls-r files normally.

Comment: For some reason, I have `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-···`.

Comment: but that's the system tree maintained under sudo normally. For non sudo use you should be using `tlmgr --usermode`  so that it installs in TEXMFHOME